# different css for ie, not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i have tried a very simple code, dont know why it is not working , may be a small mistake but i gave up, so please help

my ie version is 8.

here is my code

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <head>

         <!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" />
            <![endif]-->

          </head>
       <body>

          <div class="u">
            xyz 
          </div>

        <style scoped>

           .u{
      background:red;

     }

     </style>

         </body>
         </html>
```

ie.css

```
           .u{background:green;}
```

Comment: a) Your question is quite poor (“doesn’t work”). b) IE 8 does not know scoped styles (which are an HTML5 feature, that even some current browsers have not implemented yet) – but due to its high error tolerance it will most likely treat this style inside the body element like any other regular embedded stylesheet, and then because of the same selector it simply overwrites what you are trying to achieve with your IE 8-specific stylesheet above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are redeclaring your css.

In the above code, you are specifying:

```
For ie: set background green.
For all: set background red.
```

Place your ie css below the generic css for it to take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to apply the !important attribute to your over-riding class definition like this:

```
 .u{background:green!important;}
```

This will force it to take precedence over the normal version. A better solution might be to make it more specific too so that it is used when present (when being viewed in IE9+):

```
body div.u{background:green;}
```